# Get Average Time using Joda Time

Tags: java, time, distance, jodatime, average

I'm using a Joda Time Period to sum multiple time values. Starting at a time of 00:00:00, I am adding each amount of time to get a total amount of time for all activities. I would like to take the total time found through summing all time values and divide by the total distance to get an average time per unit of measurement.

Code:

```
    builder = new PeriodFormatterBuilder();
    builder.printZeroAlways()
            .minimumPrintedDigits(2)
            .appendHours()
            .appendSeparator(":")
            .appendMinutes()
            .appendSeparator(":")
            .appendSeconds();

    PeriodFormatter formatter = builder.toFormatter();
    PeriodParser parser = builder.toParser();

    String zero = "00:00:00";
    MutablePeriod start = new MutablePeriod();
    MutablePeriod adding = new MutablePeriod();
    parser.parseInto(start, zero, 0, Locale.getDefault());

    System.out.println("Orig Time: "+formatter.print(start));

    float total = 0;

    for (Activity temp : last7acts) {
        System.out.println(temp.getCatName()+" - "+temp.getTime()+" - "+temp.getDistance()+" "+temp.getUnits());
        total = total + temp.getDistance();
        String add = temp.getTime();
        parser.parseInto(adding, add, 0, Locale.getDefault());
        start.add(adding);
        System.out.println("Adding Time: "+formatter.print(start));
        if (start.getSeconds() > 60) {

            int origSeconds = start.getSeconds();
            int newMinutes = origSeconds / 60;
            int newSeconds = origSeconds % 60;

            start.addMinutes(newMinutes);
            start.setSeconds(newSeconds);

        }

        if (start.getMinutes() > 60) {

            int origMinutes = start.getMinutes();
            int newHours = origMinutes / 60;
            int newMinutes = origMinutes % 60;

            start.addHours(newHours);
            start.setMinutes(newMinutes);
        }
        System.out.println("Altered Time: "+formatter.print(start));

    }

    System.out.println("Final Distance: "+total);
    System.out.println("Final Time: "+formatter.print(start));
```

Output:

```
    Orig Time: 00:00:00

    Run - 00:16:08 - 2.0 miles
    Adding Time: 00:16:08
    Altered Time: 00:16:08

    Run - 00:18:09 - 2.21 miles
    Adding Time: 00:34:17
    Altered Time: 00:34:17

    Run - 00:23:35 - 2.69 miles
    Adding Time: 00:57:52
    Altered Time: 00:57:52

    Run - 00:34:45 - 4.29 miles
    Adding Time: 00:91:97
    Altered Time: 01:32:37

    Run - 00:36:15 - 4.17 miles
    Adding Time: 01:68:52
    Altered Time: 02:08:52

    Run - 00:18:03 - 2.14 miles
    Adding Time: 02:26:55
    Altered Time: 02:26:55

    Run - 00:17:27 - 2.19 miles
    Adding Time: 02:43:82
    Altered Time: 02:44:22

    Run - 00:43:43 - 5.1 miles
    Adding Time: 02:87:65
    Altered Time: 03:28:05

    Distance: 24.79
    Final Time: 03:28:05
```

What would be the best approach for dividing the Final Time of 03:28:05 by 24.79 to get an average time per unit?

Comment: What does your variable start mean? Which type?

Comment: How about convert time into seconds divide by your miles and you get how many seconds per mile?

Comment: Thanks gfgaxiola, that was one option, but was curious if there functionality available to perform division on time without converting. Apparently not.

Comment: Meno - the start variable is of MutablePeriod type. I'm initializing it with "00:00:00" time and using it to sum the times together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my late answer:

```
  PeriodFormatterBuilder builder = new PeriodFormatterBuilder();

  PeriodFormatter formatter =
    builder.printZeroAlways()
      .minimumPrintedDigits(2)
      .appendHours()
      .appendSeparator(":")
      .appendMinutes()
      .appendSeparator(":")
      .appendSeconds()
      .toFormatter();

  String zero = "00:00:00";
  Period period = formatter.parsePeriod(zero);
  float total = 0;

  for (Activity temp : last7acts) {
    System.out.println(
      temp.getCatName() + " - " + temp.getTime()
      + " - " + temp.getDistance() + " " + temp.getUnits());
    total += temp.getDistance();
    period = period.plus(formatter.parsePeriod(temp.getTime()));
  }

  period = period.normalizedStandard(PeriodType.dayTime().withDaysRemoved());
  System.out.println("Final Distance: " + total);
  System.out.println("Final Time: " + formatter.print(period));

  long secs = period.toStandardDuration().getStandardSeconds();
  NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
  System.out.println(nf.format(secs / total) + " seconds/mile");

  long minutes = secs / 60;
  System.out.println(nf.format(minutes / total) + " minutes/mile");
```

Look how short the loop has become! The immutable `Period` type is in general the better choice, and it offers normalizing capabilities what you needed and tried to do manually in lengthy fashion.